# Changing the Server in the Excel External data Connection

Tags: excel, connection-string, excel-external-data

we are currently retrieving data from our SQL Database for various purposes.
But we are shifting our Sql Database to a new Server. I need to change the Server link to the new server. I have tried changing the Server name in the Connection String at the Connection Properties window. But it doesnt work.

I have given the Connection Type Connection String details below for your reference.

The Server Name given in he below settings are Jr-erpsrv-02. I need to change this to Jr-erpsrv-03.

> 1)  Connection Type : Database Query
>
> ```
> DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=JR-ERPSRV-03;UID=Shakila;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office XP;WSID=YFHO-WKSTATION
> ```
>
> 2) Connection Type : Database Query
>
> ```
> DSN=Syspro;Description=Syspro;UID=ramya;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=2007 Microsoft Office system;WSID=ITSYSPRO-NB;DATABASE=SysproDSPL
> ```
>
> 3) Connection Type : Office Data Connection
>
> ```
>  Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=SysproDSPL;Data Source=JR-ERPSRV-02;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=ACIT-PC1;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False
> ```

Comment: What does "Does not work" mean. Do you get an error when you try to use this connection after changing? Did the SQL Server change versions as well as server names?

Comment: The SQL server is upgraded from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2016. The server name is changed from Jr-erpsrv-02 to jr-erpsrv-03.